# Printing Contents and Count of Trie in C

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, printing, trie

I am working on code that will print out the words contained in a trie and note the amount of times that the word occurred. I thought the most effective way would be for a letter to be stored in the element of the relevant node when a word is added to the trie. Occurrences is basically a flag to signal the end of a word, and is incremented if it is the last letter of a word (indicating the word count).

My struggle at this point is how to get the loop to check all of the children of a node, rather than in a straight line as it is doing right now, but I can't visualize how it would work. Ideas?

```
struct Node{
    char letter;
    struct Node children[26];
    int occurences;
};

printTrie(struct node root){
    int i = 1;
    while(root[i] != NULL){
        fprint(root.letter);
        printTrie(root->children[]);
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: That isn't valid C code. `root[i]` isn't valid for `root` that is a `struct` *anything*, much less a mysterious `struct node`, which is not provided in your code list. Post *real* code, *please*.

Comment: This looks like you're missing a number of asterisks `*` indicating pointers.  You can't have an array of `struct Node` inside a `struct Node`; the universe isn't big enough to hold the structure.  You can have an array of `struct Node *` (pointers to `struct Node`).  You function call should probably be taking a `struct Node *root` too — it currently takes a `struct node` by value, but you've not shown what a `struct node` looks like, beyond it is unrelated to the `struct Node` that you show (C is a case-sensitive language).

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)), here is how you do it:

```
if(root != NULL) {
    printf("%c\n", &root->letter);
    printf("%d\n", &root->occurences);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        printTrie(root->children[i]); /* <-- Recursion */
    }
}
```

Right now, it will print the value of the root *first*, then the value of each child.

If you want it to print the value of each child before the root, move the `printf` to be ***after*** the for-loop